# What to use for data analysis

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hbase, riak, couchbase

I have 500GB of unstructured data. The way I wish to use it is to build multiple views of this data for easy and quick consumption. Any new data entering the system should get indexed in all the views that it has to and then get stored in raw format somewhere. Apart from this, the system should have capability for adhoc queries. These queries can take non-trivial time to run. I am considering Cassandra+Hadoop+Hive, HBase, Couchbase and Riak as possible candidates for my use case.

More data will keep coming in and I plan to keep at most a couple of TBs of data in the system at any point of time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've left a lot of important details out of this question.  Important factors when deciding on a data store are, roughly, as follows:

- *How will my your be accessed?* You touched upon this in mentioning that it is unstructured and that you would like there to be many indexes available to you, but you've omitted some use case information.  When fetching information, will you be looking for a complete record or only bits an pieces of one at a time?  Document and key-value stores provide entire records, whereas tabular data stores can pull out specific bits of information per row.
- *Where in the spectrum outlined by the [ACID spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) do you lay?* Do you care about long term availability of data? If not, something like memcached can offer staggering performance.  This will likely be the most helpful, as most modern distributed data stores have carved out a niche on this spectrum (or, at least, made it possible to optimize it one way or the other).
- *How do you want to manipulate your data?* If the MapReduce paradigm is one that caters to your data set and computations, then I'd certainly recommend a combination of HBase/Cassandra (though Cassandra's MapReduce support is younger) and Hadoop.

The more information you provide, the better your/our assessment will be.

Comment: Great reply. I just wanted to mention that we also have map/reduce built into Riak.

Comment: Yeah -- certainly worth mentioning.  I actually just recently had an opportunity to play with Riak and must say I was quite impressed!  Incredibly low barrier to entry and performed excellently -- and I've always got love for Erlang.